# SoftLayer_Hardware_Server : Error Creating hardDrives larger than 500 GB

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to create Hardware Server with 1 TB of HardDisk,

When I call this code:

```
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Hardware_Server', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$call = $client->getCreateObjectOptions();
```

I See only one option with 500 GB capacity under: hardDrives.

```
(
[itemPrice] => stdClass Object
(
[hourlyRecurringFee] => 0
[recurringFee] => 0
[item] => stdClass Object
(
[description] => 500 GB SATA 
)    
)

[template] => stdClass Object
(
[hardDrives] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[hardwareComponentModelId] => 
[hardwareId] => 
[id] => 
[modifyDate] => 
[serviceProviderId] => 
[capacity] => 500
)    
)    
)    
)
```

How Can I Create Hard Disk with 1 TB ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::createObject method you can not do it, you only can use the configuration displayed by SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::getCreateObjectOptions method.

The only way is use the SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder method which is the method that the control portal uses to order, but the drawback is that is not so easy to create order. you can see more informationation about that in this [article](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3)

The other way is order your bare metal with 500 GB and once it is deployed performs an upgrade to 1 TB.

Regards